# How to get a values from array and display as select list option

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

In the database for WordPress in one of the plugins the values where entered as array into the fields from the admin. Now I want to get the values from that array and display in the page.

I created a function, This works fine.

```
// Pull district from database
function get_district(){
    global $wpdb;
    $current_demand = get_metadata('post', 205, 'field_52a7cb0d1edb0');
    return $current_demand;
}
```

On the page where I want to use the array values I did the var_dump to check for the results. This also works great

```
var_dump(get_district());
```

The values returns from the results where in this format. From what I can say is that its a array.

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> array(12) { 
    ["key"]=> string(19) "field_52a7cb0d1edb0" 
    ["label"]=> string(8) "District" 
    ["name"]=> string(8) "district" 
    ["type"]=> string(6) "select" 
    ["instructions"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["required"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["choices"]=> array(10) { 
        ["suva"]=> string(4) "Suva" 
        ["nausori"]=> string(7) "Nausori" 
        ["nadi"]=> string(4) "Nadi" 
        ["lautoka"]=> string(7) "Lautoka" 
        ["ba"]=> string(2) "Ba" 
        ["tavua"]=> string(5) "Tavua" 
        ["rakiraki"]=> string(8) "RakiRaki" 
        ["tailevu"]=> string(7) "Tailevu" 
        ["navua"]=> string(5) "Navua" 
        ["labasa"]=> string(6) "Labasa" 
    } 
    ["default_value"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["allow_null"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["multiple"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["conditional_logic"]=> array(3) { 
        ["status"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["rules"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(2) { 
                ["field"]=> string(4) "null" 
                ["operator"]=> string(2) "==" 
            } 
        } 
        ["allorany"]=> string(3) "all" 
    } 
    ["order_no"]=> int(1) 
  } 
}
```

So What I did next was to break it down and look for the specific values from the array. Now I' am running this code on the function

```
    foreach(get_district() as $district => $key){
        $test = $key["choices"];
        var_dump($test);
    }
```

The results returned from above code was

```
array(10) { 
    ["suva"]=> string(4) "Suva" 
    ["nausori"]=> string(7) "Nausori" 
    ["nadi"]=> string(4) "Nadi" 
    ["lautoka"]=> string(7) "Lautoka" 
    ["ba"]=> string(2) "Ba" 
    ["tavua"]=> string(5) "Tavua" 
    ["rakiraki"]=> string(8) "RakiRaki" 
    ["tailevu"]=> string(7) "Tailevu" 
    ["navua"]=> string(5) "Navua" 
    ["labasa"]=> string(6) "Labasa" 
}
```

**Here's my question, How can I now get the values from here to a select list. This are correct values that I want to use inside the select list. This is the first time am seeing something like this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$districts =get_district(); /* get all data */
$options="";
/* loop through all the choices array  */
foreach($districts[0]['choices'] as $key => $val){
$options.="<option value='".$key."'>".$val."</option>";
    /* append the options of select in $options  */
}
```

In html

```
<select name="districts">
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php%20%27foreach%27) loop is your best bet.

```
<?php
    $selectData = get_district();
    $selectData = $selectData[0]['choices'];

    $select = "<select>";
    foreach($selectData as $key => $value){
        $select .= "<option value='$value'>$key</option>";
    }
    $select .= "</select>";
```

Comment: Sorry, this code gave me "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in"

Comment: @navneil-naicker I was referencing the wrong array element.  I've updated the code $selectData = $selectData[0]['choices'];